# Clicking on the white space won't trigger the event in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a `ListBox` with `TextBlock`s in it that each have a `MouseLeftButtonUp` event. The size of the `ListBox` is wider than the text and when I click on the white space next to the text in the `ListBox` the event won't trigger. It still selects the item, covering it in blue, but the event won't trigger until I click on the text.

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 0, 10, 10">
    <TextBlock Name="X2" Text="X2, Power Head" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_X2" />
    <TextBlock Name="UB2X" Text="UB2X, Cab Car" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_UB2X" />
    <TextBlock Name="UA2" Text="UA2, 1st Class" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_UA2" />
    <TextBlock Name="UB2" Text="UB2, 2nd Class" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_UB2" />
    <TextBlock Name="URB2" Text="URB2, Bistro" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_URB2" />
    <TextBlock Name="URB2A" Text="URB2A, Bistro A" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_URB2A" />
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an `ItemContainerStyle` to stretch the `ListBoxItem` content (your `TextBlock`s) to the full width.

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 0, 10, 10">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <TextBlock Name="X2" Text="X2, Power Head" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_X2" />
   <TextBlock Name="UB2X" Text="UB2X, Cab Car" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_UB2X" />
   <TextBlock Name="UA2" Text="UA2, 1st Class" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_UA2" />
   <TextBlock Name="UB2" Text="UB2, 2nd Class" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_UB2" />
   <TextBlock Name="URB2" Text="URB2, Bistro" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_URB2" />
   <TextBlock Name="URB2A" Text="URB2A, Bistro A" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Selected_URB2A" />
</ListBox>
```